# OSX Spotlight not removing web searches

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, spotlight

[image]

I've unchecked everything but I still can't seem to remove the websearches. Is there a way to turn that off? I've tried adding volume to privacy and removing it to rebuild the index, no go.

Also there's an exclamation point next to my spotlight shortcut. I can't seem to find the conflict in the keyboard shortcuts tab

Comment: To clarify, you are aware that you need to *click* on these items so anything actually happens? OS X is *not* performing the web search automatically, as it doesn't show any results. These are just displayed for convenience.

Comment: Regarding that conflict, have you checked Mission Control preferences?

Comment: I just don't want those results in Spotlight since I absolutely will never use them. I've checked Mission Control prefs and none of the shortcuts conflict with spotlight shortcut.